# Query using % with IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been looking for this answer here but could not find any, the question is this.

This is the table

```
USER    | PERMISSION
PEDRO   | ALL
BARBARA | READ - WRITE
FULANO  | WRITE
```

Its a exemple table, what I want is to query all users that have ALL in permission and any user that has the permission I want for that page, like READ or WRITE using IN

I'm using this:

```
select * from senha where permission IN ('read', 'all')
```

Its only querying the "pedro" because it has all, and not "barbara" because it has more words insted of just READ, tried this too but no success

```
select * from senha where permission IN ('%read%', 'all')
```

Comment: IN works like =; you want a version of IN that works like LIKE - and that doesn't exist.  Perhaps you should rethink your database schema; if there were a many-to-many association between USER and PERMISSION, this would be easier.

Comment: Tell me you are confused between `in` and `like` query syntax..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve `LIKE` like behavior using `IN`. Use `OR` to combine the two clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM senha 
WHERE (permission = 'ALL' OR permission LIKE '%READ%')
```

As for your revised question, the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM senha
WHERE user  = 'PEDRO' AND 
      senha = 'TEST'  AND 
      (permission = 'ALL' OR permission LIKE '%READ%')
```

Having said that, I would rather normalize the permissions, like this for example:

```text
USER    | PERMISSION
--------+-----------
PEDRO   | ALL
BARBARA | READ
BARBARA | WRITE
FULANO  | WRITE
```

Comment: Its not that simple, I tried using OR but I add more arguments using AND it misses all of then and uses just the OR... like this.
SELECT * FROM senha WHERE user like "pedro" and senha like "test" AND permission = = 'all' or permission like '%read%'... it misses everyting and just uses the OR PERMISSION LIKE '%read%'...

Comment: Then you must learn how operator precedence work! You should be able to achieve the desired results by grouping the clauses inside `(` and `)`.